# useReducer with useContext results with Typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context, use-reducer

I'm trying to create a context that holds state and reducer.
But it gives me error messages on the return statement and I just don't know what to do:

Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'RegExp'.ts(2365)
Unterminated regular expression literal.ts(1161)

```
import { createContext, FunctionComponent, PropsWithChildren, ReactNode, useReducer } from "react";
import reducer from "./reducer";

// stored data
export type storeType = {
    message: string | null
};

const initialState: storeType = {
    message: null
}

const AppContext = createContext<storeType>(initialState);

const CxtProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
    const [currentState, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    return <AppContext.Provider value={{
        currentState,
        dispatch
    }}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
};

export default CxtProvider;
```

Anyone knows, what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

---

EDIT1:
Thanks for the idea, I tried spreading the object, but didn't help, there's even more error now.

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in src/utils/context/context.ts
TS1161: Unterminated regular expression literal.

ERROR in src/utils/context/context.ts:19:13
TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'AppContext'.

ERROR in src/utils/context/context.ts:19:33
TS1005: '>' expected.

ERROR in src/utils/context/context.ts:19:33
TS2304: Cannot find name 'value'.

ERROR in src/utils/context/context.ts:19:38
TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in src/utils/context/context.ts:20:9
TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

ERROR in src/utils/context/context.ts:20:12
TS2304: Cannot find name 'currentState'.

ERROR in src/utils/context/context.ts:20:12
TS2695: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.

ERROR in src/utils/context/context.ts:21:9
TS2304: Cannot find name 'dispatch'.

ERROR in src/utils/context/context.ts:22:6
TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

ERROR in src/utils/context/context.ts:22:7
TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

ERROR in src/utils/context/context.ts:22:8
TS1109: Expression expected.

ERROR in src/utils/context/context.ts:22:8
TS2365: Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'RegExp'.

ERROR in src/utils/context/context.ts:22:10
TS18004: No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'children'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.

ERROR in src/utils/context/context.ts:23:1
TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the things you're returning in `()`

Comment: @RubenSmn yes I did, the result is still the same

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally it solved by diverting the parts into different files:
context, reducer, provider. No idea why.

Thanks for ideas

I suppose the problem was somewhere in createContext type didn't have the reducer member

Comment: the problem here was using JSX syntax inside TS file. you needed TSX extension instead

Answer (score 2):

You should unwrap the `currentState` values:

```
return <AppContext.Provider value={{
          ...currentState,
          dispatch
       }}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
```

Comment: Hmm... that didn't work. The errors stays

Comment: @sjiamnocna Can you post the `reducer` code?